# Unable to get to wp-admin log in page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, pluggable

Hi I have recently tried to log in to my site and I keep getting the following error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /homepages/6/d700752663/htdocs/clickandbuilds/OnyxMotorsCompany/wp-content/themes/cardealer/includes/base_functions.php:1)
>   in
>   /homepages/6/d700752663/htdocs/clickandbuilds/OnyxMotorsCompany/wp-includes/pluggable.php
>   on line 1210

I have not made any changes to website. The website itself works fine however I cannot get to wordpress dashboard either via `wp-login` and `wp-admin`.

Any idea? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to go back to a default wordpress theme and test it again ? Maybe a plugin update itself automatically or something similar that affects your wordpress theme?

Comment: I cannot get to dashboard therefor I am unable to change default theme

Comment: you can change it through phpmyadmin  by modifying wp_options table, there one or two records holds the name of the activated theme

Comment: look at this file `wp-content/themes/cardealer/includes/base_functions.php` delete all spaces before first opening `<?php` tag. also, check if there is '?>'. if so delete spaces before it

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan I have done it already, no luck. I will edit my post and add entire code if possible so someone can review it

Comment: Following @SamvelAleqsanyan thoughts: the file isn't in UTF-8 *with BOM*, is it? If it is with bom, try making it utf-8 without bom. Good luck!

Comment: @FelipeElia, I have done that too. NO luck.

Comment: The code is too long to insert it here. Any idea what I should do to enter it here?

Comment: it's simple just goto cpanel or FTP and rename your current theme by any word after the name like theme0 and then access the admin page
once you loggedin try to activate another theme then rename your theme which was theme0 to theme (original name) and then activate it hope it works or you can add the same theme with latest or current version again or by simply replacing the functions.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Open base_functions.php & try and add following code on top.

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
```

You have already marked path to file: /homepages/6/d700752663/htdocs/clickandbuilds/OnyxMotorsCompany/wp-content/themes/cardealer/includes/base_functions.php

I hope it will help.